# Will be there any considerable performance raise if we use tag#id instead of #id while accessing DOM elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, performance

Is the following equation true in terms of execution time ?

```
 Is   $('#id') > $('div#id')
```

I tried using console.time(), to measure the time and the results are not consistent.

Comment: what are you trying to do??

Comment: Ya, in all cases but difference would be in nano seconds. Now post code you are using trying to debug it

Comment: `div#id` usage is somehow slow.

Comment: Thanks @A.WolffMy code doesn't have millions of div's, but i am curious to know if there is any difference between both.

Answer (score 4):

> Will be there any considerable performance raise if we use tag#id instead of #id while accessing DOM elements using jquery

If "performance raise" means "better (faster) performance," then no, quite the opposite, not that it's likely to matter.

> Is the following equation true in terms of execution time ?
>
> ```
> Is   $('#id') > $('div#id')
> ```

No, the raw ID selector is optimized to a call to `getElementById`, which is **dramatically** faster than `querySelectorAll` (or in the worse case, Sizzle's own handling if it can't find `querySelectorAll`) when called with a compound tag and ID selector.

The difference is unlikely to *matter*, though, unless you're doing it millions of times in a tight loop, which seems unlikely.

Also note that the two selectors are not equivalent:

`#id` looks for any element that has that `id`, regardless of its tag, and returns just one, even in an invalid HTML document that uses the `id` more than once. (Specifically, [the first one](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyid), but as the document is invalid if the `id` is repeated, I wouldn't rely on that, not least because the [previous specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) said the behavior was undefined.)

`div#id` will only look for `div` elements with that `id`, ignoring any others. So if you have `<span id="id">...</span>`, it won't get found, because although it has the `id`, it's not a `div`. `div#id` will also return multiple elements when used in an invalid HTML document that has more than one `div` with that `id` (although since the document is invalid, I wouldn't rely on it; instead, I'd make the document valid by making the `id` unique and using something else to group those elements, like a class).